# Check for the presence of a parameter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an issue with checking for presence of my parameter.
I have:

```html
<%= f.autocomplete_field :client, autocomplete_client_name_requests_path, class: "form-control",:update_elements => {} %>
```

and params look like that:

```html
evm: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  in: '18'
  client: Makayla Blick
  ..etc
```

I my create action i want to check for presence of the value of client parameter:

```html
 if params[:client].present?
      ..some code
 end
```

But after debugging i found out that I do not enter that if statement.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ouh, silly mistake, it should be

```html
if params[:evm][:client_id].present?
```